# Subquery returned more than 1 value not permitted

Tags: sql

I have a subquery which is giving me the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value

Where am I going wrong?

```
CASE WHEN @fund LIKE '123%'    
                THEN 
                        (SELECT ((SELECT (Nav.valueFund) 
                        FROM Nav WHERE fund = @fund and navDate = @navdate AND classification = 'Investments')
                        / ((SELECT ((SELECT SUM(Nav.valueFund) FROM Nav WHERE fund = @fund and navDate = @navdate))
                        + (SELECT LiqS.Amount FROM LiqS WHERE fund = @fund and Date = @navdate))))*100)                   
    ELSE (enav.exposureFundPerNAV) *100
```

Comment: Voting to close as "why isn't this code working?"  We can't read your mind to figure out what your intended logic is.  Please tell us what this code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: The code is intended to return a % for each type of instrument

Comment: The error message is quite clear, but to help you we need to understand what you are trying to do. Describe the problem you're trying to solve. Show us sample table data and the expected result (both as formatted text, not images.) But first of all, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Answer (score 0):

First subquery (`SELECT Nav.valueFund`) doesn't have **Aggregate functions** to produce single result (as we see in second query `SELECT SUM(Nav.valueFund)`), using functions like `SUM`, `MAX`, `MIN` which ever applicable for first sub query removes the error or else `TOP(1)` to get only one result.